# create a new pandas dataframe by taking values from a different dataframe and perforing some mathematical operations on it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a pandas dataframe with 16 columns and approx 1000 rows, 
the format is like this

```
date_time   sec01   sec02   sec03   sec04   sec05   sec06   sec07   sec08   sec09   sec10   sec11   sec12   sec13   sec14   sec15   sec16

1970-01-01 05:54:17 8.50    8.62    8.53    8.45    8.50    8.62    8.53    8.45    8.42    8.39    8.39    8.40    8.47    8.54    8.65    8.70
1970-01-01 05:56:55 8.43    8.62    8.55    8.45    8.43    8.62    8.55    8.45    8.42    8.39    8.39    8.40    8.46    8.53    8.65    8.71
```

and now I need to make another pandas dataframe with 32 columns:

```
x_sec01 y_sec01 x_sec02 y_sec02 x_sec03 y_sec03 x_sec04 y_sec04 x_sec05 y_sec05 x_sec06 y_sec06 x_sec07 ...
```

where the values of each column needs to be multiplied with a specific mathematical constant which is dependent on the column number (sector number):

```
x = sec_data * (math.cos(math.radians(1.40625*(sector_number))))
y = sec_data * (math.sin(math.radians(1.40625*(sector_number))))
```

Thus each columns in the original pandas dataframe (sec01-sec16) needs to be converted to two columns (x_sec01,y_sec01) and the factor by which it has to be multiplied depends on the sector_number value.

Currently I am using this function and calling this for every single rows in a for loop that is taking too much of time.

```
def sec_to_xy(sec_no,sec_data):  #function to convert sector data to xy coordinate system
    for sec_convno in range(0,32,2):
        sector_number = (77-(sec_no-1)*2) #goes from 79 till 49
        x = sec_data * (math.cos(math.radians(1.40625*(sector_number))))
        y = sec_data * (math.sin(math.radians(1.40625*(sector_number))))   
    return(x,y)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general idea is to stack your values so you can apply numpy's fast, vectorized functions.

```
# stack the dataframe
df2 = df.stack().reset_index(level=1)
df2.columns = ['sec', 'value']
# extract the sector number
df2['sec_no'] = df2['sec'].str.slice(-2).astype(int)

# apply numpy's vectorized functions
import numpy as np
df2['x'] = df2['value'] * (np.cos(np.radians(1.40625*(df2['sec_no']))))
df2['y'] = df2['value'] * (np.sin(np.radians(1.40625*(df2['sec_no']))))
```

At this stage, here is what `df2` looks like:

```
                       sec  value  sec_no         x         y
1970-01-01 05:54:17  sec01   8.50       1  8.497440  0.208600
1970-01-01 05:54:17  sec02   8.62       2  8.609617  0.422963
1970-01-01 05:54:17  sec03   8.53       3  8.506888  0.627506
1970-01-01 05:54:17  sec04   8.45       4  8.409311  0.828245
1970-01-01 05:54:17  sec05   8.50       5  8.436076  1.040491
```

Now pivot the table to return to the original shape:

```
df2[['sec', 'x', 'y']].pivot(columns='sec')
```

All that is left to do is rename the columns.

Comment: i understood the first part but the second part doesn't seem to be working i am getting this 'cannot label index with a null key' error

Comment: yes, i'm looking at it right now, sorry i'm very new to programming

Comment: What pandas version do you have (`pd.__version__`)? Can you try `.pivot(index=df2.index, columns='sec')`?

Comment: the pandas version is '0.13.1' and tried this one also but now im getting 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape', i think im doing something really stupid here

Comment: If you upgraded to the latest pandas version it would work. It's difficult for me to fix the problem in an older version. Have you tried the other answer maybe?

Comment: i will update the pandas version check it, i think it'll work after that.
thanks for the help sir, have a great day

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach with NumPy -

```
# Extract as float array
a = df.values # Extract all 16 columns
m,n = a.shape

# Scaling array
s = np.radians(1.40625*(np.arange(79,47,-2)))

# Initialize output array and set cosine and sine values
out = np.zeros((m,n,2))
out[:,:,0] = a*np.cos(s)
out[:,:,1] = a*np.sin(s)

# Transfer to a dataframe output
df_out = pd.DataFrame(out.reshape(-1,n*2),index=df.index)
```

Please note that if there are actually 17 columns with the first column being `date_time`, then we need to skip the first column. So, at the start, get `a` with the following step instead -

```
a = df.ix[:,1:].values
```